# joinUrl obtained from GRAPH API /app/onlinemeeting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, graph, microsoft-teams, microsoft-live-meeting

I created, to be displayed on my asp mvc application (app that is declared on Azure). I get the joinUrl that address the MS teams application .

1. Is it possible to get only the call interface **and not all the teams application** from the joinUrl response?
2. When I try to embed the link in a iframe I get **CORS policy issue** - Is there any way to display the teams url in a asp net page?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get only the call interface from a teams application. We do not have any APIs to do so also we do not have any plans to add this.